# Ubuntu crashes at boot after installing new RAM sticks

Tags: boot, ram, crash

I tried to upgrade my existing 4GB RAM with 8GB RAM sticks on my Asus Aspire 5733z, however when I try to start up it goes straight to the GRUB menu and won't let me boot Ubuntu. I tried two different slots and a different RAM stick, but it didn't work.

When I put back the old 4GB sticks and boot it prints a string of repetitive errors as shown below. After that it boots to Ubuntu like normal.

[image: boot messages]

Comment: Have you validated your memory 'new' sticks (ie. run memtest86).  Before I trust new hardware I test before I try and booting something I do care about...

Comment: status please...

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

1. For 18.04 or newer... lets fix your file system...

   - boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
   - open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
   - type `sudo fdisk -l`
   - identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
   - type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
   - repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
   - type `reboot`

---

2. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.